# How to update data from an API

Tags: real-time-updates

I'm currently working on a project where I'm pulling data from the Aviation Week API and saving it into a database. However, I've encountered a challenge with the update process.

Here's the situation:

- The Aviation Week API returns a large dataset with 248,764 records just for 1 endpoint.
- Due to API limitations, I can only retrieve 150 records per call.

Now, the issue arises when I need to update these records. There isn't a field in the data indicating the last updated time, so I can't efficiently identify which records have been updated since the last pull.
Has anyone else encountered a similar challenge? I'm seeking advice on how to efficiently handle updates without resorting to pulling the entire dataset repeatedly.

I'm trying to avoid making redundant API calls, so any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

As a result, I find myself needing to pull the entire dataset again to check for updates.

Comment: The real problem too is that as you are doing 1900 updates, there is a chance that the data has changed again during this update, and another update happened, and it was outside of the list of updates, so it will be missed.  If you had control over the data (a table vs apI situation) you could use a lock to keep the table from updating, but since you don't own the API , it just depends how essential the updates are, in the sense, if you miss some during an update, is the next batch in an hour or something frequent so it stays mostly up to do?

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to double store data, which I'd strongly recommend against, is there a reason you couldn't just call the API when you needed the individual record? You'd still probably have to store identifiers for those records, but you wouldn't need to police the data changes. Otherwise you may look into webhooks, if they provide any.

Comment: @easley so far I am pulling the information, and comparing each of the records and checking if each of them has changed if changed updated it.
but there doing that per record is a very slow process when there is 248,764 records and I can only get 150 records per call.

Comment: MentallyRecursive unfortunately the API documentation doesn't mention anything about webhooks.
The company that I work for wants to keep all those records in the local DB, so they can play with the information as need it.
So far I think and I hope not to be double storing data.
if you were in my position what would you do? any recommendation?